# Could not get unknown property 'experimentalProperties' for extension 'android' | Android Jetpack Macrobenchmark

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle, android-jetpack

I am following macrobenchmark setup configurations from -
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/macrobenchmark#configuration

In following code in my macrobenchmark's build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    targetProjectPath = ":app" // Note that your module name may be different
    experimentalProperties["android.experimental.self-instrumenting"] = true
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable = true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

following build error is thrown while gradle sync:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':macrobenchmark'.
> Could not get unknown property 'experimentalProperties' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.TestExtension.
```

I'm new to android, any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the error, via following -

1. Updated Android Studio to Arctic Fox Beta Version
2. Updated gradle version in project build.gradle to 7.0 beta4

Found solution through [documentation of benchmark samples](https://github.com/android/performance-samples/blob/main/MacrobenchmarkSample/README.md#running) repository provided by google and comparing gradle files.

Answer (score 1):

Due other dependencies I had to update to version 7.1.0-alpha02 of gradle plugin in project build.gradle file.

And this property got recognized.